# cannot start neo4j server using plugin

Tags: java, plugins, neo4j

I have created a 2 server plugins and packaged the jar file into `var/lib/neo4j/plugins` one by one. For one jar file I\m able to start server, but with another jar file I get following error:

> Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:146)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:118)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.peek(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:50)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:36)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:91)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:82)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:275) Okt
>   26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]:         ... 11 more
>   Okt 26 13:01:05 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[24787]: 2017-10-26
>   11:01:05.344+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request

To create the jar file I'm using:

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: What was the exception? Show your entire stack trace.

Comment: @cybersam  This is what I get on CLI